# Forking a multi-threaded process

Tags: multithreading, locking, fork, getaddrinfo

I have an application that has two threads. One thread forks on an event and other thread is doing something which results into a lot of getaddrinfo() calls.
I am facing an issue where in some cases forked child hangs on a mutex inside getaddrinfo() call.

Now I understand that this only happens when child is forked while second thread in the parent process is in getaddinfo() call. This results into a deadlock because the child inherits the parent's lock but never releases it.

My question is how can one go about this issue when a system call itself is taking a lock?
Well, one way I can fix it is by synchronizing the fork system call and getaddrinfo call in both the threads. But is there any other way to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using pthread_atfork to register the pre/post-fork handlers that would lock/unlock respectively.
I guess that is the only way forward in this case.

I just wish that man pages of these calls (like getaddrinfo) mention that they take locks internally so that programmers don't fall into this pitfall.